# Rails: practice of rendering new on invalid entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While reading other peoples controllers code and some other resources, I met this kind of code a lot:

```
def create
 if @record.save
  redirect_to @record
 else
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html {render :new}
  format.json {render @record.errors}
  end
end
```

But now, just clicking my app pages for fun (this was not covered by rout testing at all), I found out - if you click submit on invalid form, you will have form rendered and current path as `/records`. But if you hit reload page, this leads to an error:

```
No route matches GET /records
```

In my case, I don't have `index` action, or you will be redirected to index page, which is also rather inconvenient.

Is there any other way of being redirected back to `/new` but without loosing form inputs or error messages, as it happens with render?

Can I do something like this?

```
redirect_to new_record_path
respond_to do |format|
format.json {render @record}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`render` loads a view without calling another action. The data from the  action containing the `render` call is used to render that view. That is why the form data can be displayed in that view.

`redirect_to` starts a new request that calls the action associated with the route. Since a new action is called, the data from the previously called action is not available to the view that the client is directed to.